# JQuery Accordion with Galleria inside a section problem

Tags: jquery, accordion, galleria

I have a problem with Galleria. 
I'm using the JQuery accordion as my main layout and inside one section I have Galleria http://galleria.aino.se/.

My problem is that if you load the index without any parameter, the home section is opened. 
And then if you click on the gallery section, galleria seems to be working indefinitely. 
If you click the next arrow to navigate, the thumbnails seems to go back and forth and not showing the right image. 

In Chrome, the main image never load.

But if you reload the page with the gallery section opened, all works fine.

Here's my website: http://www.narcissusphoto.com/

How to reproduce: 
 1- Click the "gallery" section.
 
 2- Check top right corner for the loading animation. 
 3- Click the right navigation arrow. 
 4- See that the thumbnails at the bottom are bugged and moving left and right randomly (in opera and IE). 
 4- See that the main image never load (Chrome).

Comment: To start, I would make sure your html is valid. http://validator.w3.org/check?verbose=1&uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.narcissusphoto.com%2Findex.php%3Fgallery%3D2%23clients

Comment: @SiriusNik: No need to add _"thanks"_, _"regards"_, ... at the and or start of the question, your user card will always be at the end of the question.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find a solution; binded myself to the Accordion change event and reload galleria.

```
change: function(event, ui) { LoadGalleria(); }
```

Comment: Next time you post code select the code and click the `{}` icon so it gets formatted as code.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the `api` of [Galleria](http://galleria.io/) has changed... So if anybody has the same problem now you could use the following:

```
change: function(event, ui){
  // first check whether Galleria is loaded on this page
  if(typeof(Galleria) === "function") {
    Galleria.loadTheme('path/to/your/theme.js');
  }
}
```